# Still cannot install scipy

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the python package scipy.  When I type

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

here is exactly what I get

```
mark@mark-N53SV:~$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-scipy
```

there are a lot of posts suggesting that the problem is that the universe repository isn't available, however I do have the universe repository selected so that cannot be the issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is definitely there: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-scipy Have you run: `sudo apt-get update` yet? If universe really is enabled, then it could be a problem with your mirror, so you could try a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've enabled the Universe repository, and it still does not work, that suggests that APT has not been updated to use the new configuration. (This can cause the problem you're experiencing even if it has been updated to use the new configuration, but has not been updated since other changes were made.)

I noticed you didn't mention running `sudo apt-get update`. It's a good idea to run that before installing software on the command line. If you haven't run that very recently, try that, and then see if you can install the software.

If that does not work, then the problem is usually caused by a misconfiguration of your software sources. You could have only parts of the necessary sources enabled, or you could be configured to use software sources that are broken on the server (some mirrors might malfunction or go down), or software sources for the wrong Ubuntu release or for some other operating system altogether.

So, if running `sudo apt-get update` doesn't fix the problem, take a look at the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. One way to view the contents of that file is to run:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If that doesn't clarify the cause of the problem, or you want help interpreting its contents or checking if they are correct, then please edit your question to include the ful output of that command (and also of `lsb_release -a`).

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation you need to this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

Link for more information: http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: Ok, so I tried it, it didn't work.  I must admit I can't see how this would help, it's still trying to install the same package with the same method, here is the output                                   E: Unable to locate package python-scipy
E: Unable to locate package python-matplotlib
E: Unable to locate package ipython
E: Unable to locate package ipython-notebook
E: Unable to locate package python-pandas
E: Unable to locate package python-sympy
E: Package 'python-nose' has no installation candidate               Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You should try what Eliah Kagan wrote on his answer